# IntegrityError: null value in column "image" violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django

When I register a new user the website was creating a profile automatically and was using default.jpg image. Suddenly it stopped working. And the error says that I have a problem with my 'image' field. This is the error I get:

```
IntegrityError at /accounts/register/

null value in column "image" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (20, pbkdf2_sha256$150000$72dkND5yT5M0$+/chH/5Vu76KM7oNMjU694EWFZ/p+B..., null, f, kazanda, f, 2019-04-21 17:41:29.969889+00, Andreas, Swarchft, Germany, Frankfurt, andreas_sw@gmail.com, t, null).
```

This is my models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None):
        super().save()

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 250 or img.width > 250:
            output_size = (250, 250)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)



def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = Profile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

my views.py

```
class UserRegistrationView(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationModelForm
    model = User
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    success_message = "Account for %(first_name)s was created successfully. You will get email notification when admin will activate your account!"
    template_name = 'users/registration.html'

    def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):
        return self.success_message % dict(cleaned_data)


@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uform = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        pform = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        posts = Post.objects.filter(author=request.user)

        if uform.is_valid() and pform.is_valid():
            uform.save()
            pform.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('users:cabinet')
    else:
        uform = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        pform = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
        posts = Post.objects.filter(author=request.user)

    context = {
        'uform': uform,
        'pform': pform,
        'posts': posts
    }

    return render(request, 'users/user_detail.html', context)



@login_required
def cabinet(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.all()

    context = {
        'profile': profile

    }
    return render(request, 'users/user_detail.html', context)
```

my registration.html

which is a form to create a user:

```
{% extends 'shared/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="content-section mt-5 pl-5 p-4">
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group pr-4">
      <legend class="mb-4">Join Today</legend>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
          {{ form.first_name|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
          {{ form.last_name|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
          {{ form.username|as_crispy_field }}
        <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
          {{ form.country|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
          {{ form.city|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 mb-0">
          {{ form.email|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
          {{ form.password1|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
          {{ form.password2|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="form-check">
              {{ form.access_challenge }}
          <label class="form-check-label" for="Checkbox">&nbsp;Access Challenge Country</label>
        </div> -->
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button style="border-radius: 0; width: 200px; padding-left: 4px;" class="btn btn-info btn-block" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="border-top pt-3">
    <small class="text-muted">
      Already Have An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'login' %}">Sign In</a>
    </small>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my post_form.html

```
{% extends 'shared/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

<div class="content-section mt-5 pl-5 p-4">
  <form method="post" id="personForm" data-cities-url="{% url 'users:ajax_load_cities' %}" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <legend class="mb-4">Church Info</legend>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 small">
          {{ form.area|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 small">
          {{ form.country|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 small">
          {{ form.name|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 small">
          {{ form.city|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 small">
          {{ form.email|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 small">
          {{ form.website|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 small">
          {{ form.address|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 small">
          {{ form.phone|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 small">
          {{ date_posted }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 small">
          {{ author }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button style="border-radius: 0; width: 200px; padding-left: 4px;" class="btn btn-info btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="border-top pt-3">
      <small class="text-muted">
        Already Have An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'login' %}">Sign In</a>
      </small>
    </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $("#id_area").change(function () {
      var url = $("#personForm").attr("data-cities-url");
      var areaId = $(this).val();

      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {
          'area': areaId
        },
        success: function (data) {
          $("#id_country").html(data);
        }
      });

    });
  </script>

{% endblock %}
```

Here is my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .models import Profile, Post, User, Country

class UserCreationModelForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'country', 'city', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']


class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'country', 'city', 'email']


class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']



class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('name', 'area', 'country', 'city', 'address', 'email', 'phone', 'website')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['country'].queryset = Country.objects.none()

        if 'area' in self.data:
            try:
                area_id = int(self.data.get('area'))
                self.fields['country'].queryset = Country.objects.filter(area_id=area_id).order_by('name')
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass  # invalid input from the client; ignore and fallback to empty City queryset
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['country'].queryset = self.instance.area.country_set.order_by('name')
```

Comment: what did you change?

Comment: @HenryM I was using CreateView. But I needed AJAX so I created a Form in forms.py. Then I noticed that I have this problem. Here is my form.

Comment: Aren't you sharing the wrong info then.  You need to share the ajax call and the function you're using to create the user (since you're not using the CreateView anymore).

Comment: as mentioned, provide the ajax request used

Comment: @HenryM  I added post_form.html file. All the ajax I added are there. Also I added forms.py file and where def ___init___ was the changes made.

Comment: @Lemayzeur  I added post_form.html file. All the ajax I added are there. Also I added forms.py file and where def init was the changes made.

Comment: Can't see error.  Can you add the traceback

Comment: @HenryM `DETAIL:  Failing row contains (21, pbkdf2_sha256$150000$27kadT7T4vFj$WfLt+ilZFaLOqwL30VDSO4TZ7+VCx1..., null, f, andreas, f, 2019-04-24 03:57:34.621561+00, Andreas, Johan, Germany, Frankfurt, andreas@protonmail.com, t, null).

[24/Apr/2019 03:57:34] "POST /accounts/register/ HTTP/1.1" 500 183436
`

Comment: Surely that's not the full traceback?